How to Perform Bulk Insert via Navigation Property in Entity Framework Core with Type Safety?
I have the following database structure where Student and Course are linked through a many-to-many relationship in StudentCourseLinks. I need to perform a bulk insert into StudentCourseLinks where I insert a new CourseId for all Student records that belong to a specific SchoolId.
Here are my simplified models:
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property to many-to-many relationship
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class StudentCourseLink
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}

What I want to achieve is the following SQL query in Entity Framework Core, but with type safety and bulk operations (i.e., avoiding multiple round trips to the database):
INSERT INTO StudentCourseLinks (StudentId, CourseId)
SELECT s.Id, 1
FROM Students s
WHERE s.SchoolId = 1;

I want to add a new CourseId (e.g., 1) for all students that belong to SchoolId = 1, but I'd like to achieve this through Entity Framework Core's type-safe API, including using the navigation properties between Student and Course. I would like the conditional insert to also be dynamic since my conditions could change.
Is there a way to perform this bulk insert using Entity Framework Core, maintaining type safety and avoiding raw SQL?
Any guidance or solutions for this would be greatly appreciated!

What did you try? Look at the SQL generated by EF itself. It's not as bad as you seem to think (merge statements).

I played around with raw query with Dapper, adding new items to EF object and context.SaveChanges but this required round trips, I looked at EFCore.BulkExtensions but this also requires retrieving lists of things to bulkinsert, I used straight up ExecuteSqlRawAsync but not type safe. All in all, I could find no solution that offers typesafe way to compile a  single SQL insert like INSERT INTO StudentCourseLinks (StudentId, CourseId) SELECT s.Id, 1 FROM Students s WHERE s.SchoolId = 1; , which I found quite interesting. Don't want to bloat my question with examples that don't do it.

Not worried about it being bad.

The benefit of showing your own efforts is that people won't go the same paths in answers, which can be very frustrating (also for the answerer). And it shows more specifically where you're stuck. If you don't want to rely on third-party libraries you could use stub entities to establish the relationships. That's the best EF has to offer, it doesn't have bulk insert out of the box.

This is a bit of struggle to get what you want. I did not find anything exactly matching your needs. So one options is to implement something like this yourself.
The other options is to find the nuget that matches your requirements closely. There's one: N.EntityFramework.Extensions. It has InsertFromQuery method (and its async counterpart), that is able to produce INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM query.
Here's sample code snippet that I made to work, please excuse my trashy entities (setup is simple, one Movies table with FK to other Releases table, that's all)
var releaseId = Guid.Parse("76352746-f56d-485f-b135-571beb038e06");
var newMovieId = Guid.NewGuid();
await context.Movies
    .Where(x => x.Title.Length > 5)
    .InsertFromQueryAsync(
        "Movies",
        m => new  
        { 
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Title = "new title", 
            ReleaseYear = 2019,
            ReleaseId = releaseId
        });


Disclaimer: I'm the owner of Entity Framework Extensions
What you are currently looking for is our FREE InsertFromQuery feature.
context.Students.Where(x => x.SchoolId == 1)
       .InsertFromQuery("StudentCourseLinks", x => new { StudentId = x.Id, CourseId = 1});

Online Example
Only one database round-trip will be required as everything will be executed on the database side without having to load entities in your database. This is the solution with the best performance you can have.
So for your specific scenario, you don't really need to do a Bulk Insert

Using linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore. Full disclosure: I am one of the project creators.
var sourceQuery = 
    from s in context.Students
    where s.SchoolId == 1
    select new StudentCourseLink
    {
        StudentId = s.Id,
        CourceId = 1
    };

sourceQuery
    .Into(context.StudentCourseLinks.ToLinqToDBTable())
    .Insert();

Extensions`s LINQ translator handles almost all queries, so you can write even complex ones with ease.
